# change a Windows Form Control in a thread

Tags: c++, winforms, multithreading, c++-cli

I already asked something similar, but the solution I found help me partially, so I'm asking a question that is similar to my previous one.
my problem is that in the Thread I want that the text of the button change.
the thread works fine, I can see the MessageBox I'm displaying, but the text of the button remains unchanged.
how do I change it?
if I need to use the delegate (commented text), ho do I I fix it? because that code raises some errors about wrong '(' and '{' but that's the answer I got before

```
#pragma once


namespace UIThread {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Threading;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form1
///
/// WARNING: If you change the name of this class, you will need to change the
///          'Resource File Name' property for the managed resource compiler tool
///          associated with all .resx files this class depends on.  Otherwise,
///          the designers will not be able to interact properly with localized
///          resources associated with this form.
/// </summary>


public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{

public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  BtnStart;
protected: 

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->BtnStart = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // BtnStart
        // 
        this->BtnStart->Location = System::Drawing::Point(114, 38);
        this->BtnStart->Name = L"BtnStart";
        this->BtnStart->Size = System::Drawing::Size(124, 37);
        this->BtnStart->TabIndex = 0;
        this->BtnStart->Text = L"button1";
        this->BtnStart->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->BtnStart->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::BtnStart_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 262);
        this->Controls->Add(this->BtnStart);
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"Form1";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);

    }
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void BtnStart_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    Form1^ f=gcnew Form1;
    Thread^ oThread = gcnew Thread( gcnew ThreadStart( f, &Form1::ThreadMethod ) );
    oThread->Start();
}

private: void ThreadMethod(/*Object^ state*/)
{   
    BtnStart->Text="hello";
    MessageBox::Show("AAAAAA");
    //this->Invoke((Action^)delegate(){BtnStart->Text = "Hello";});
}
};
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You managed to get rid of the runtime exception that told you that you were doing it wrong.  By creating a *new* form object.  One that isn't visible because you never called its Show() method.  So you can't see the button text update either.  What you want to do is update the *existing* form object:

```
System::Void BtnStart_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    Thread^ oThread = gcnew Thread( gcnew ThreadStart( this, &Form1::ThreadMethod ) );
    oThread->Start();
}
```

You got bad advice on your previous question, that syntax only works in C#.  C++/CLI doesn't support anonymous delegates.  You have to write it out, just like you did for the ThreadStart delegate:

```
void UpdateButton() {
    BtnStart->Text="hello";
}

void ThreadMethod() {   
    this->Invoke(gcnew MethodInvoker(this, &Form1::UpdateButton));
}
```

Comment: thank you, I get somithing different now, I get a runtime error that says (I'm translating from italian), Impossible to call Invoke or BeginInvoke on a control until a windows handle is not created. any idea?

Comment: ok found!! it was a stupid error, Thread^ oThread = gcnew Thread( gcnew ThreadStart( this, &Form1::ThreadMethod ) );  using this instead of f is correct.... thank you so much, wish to double upvote your answer